# How do I use configure TbEditableColumn in Yiibooster?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to get TbEditableColumn working using Yiibooster. I have followed the instructions here http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/components.html#editable

I am confused by the line

```
'editable' => array(
'url' => $this->createUrl('site/editable'),
'placement' => 'right',
'inputclass' => 'span3'
)
```

Does that mean I should already have an actionEditable() method or need to create one?

I tried using the preexisting actionUpdate($id) method in the my image controller.

```
'editable' => array(
'url' => $this->createUrl('image/update', array('id'=>'1')),
'placement' => 'right',
'inputclass' => 'span3'
```

ATM it updates the front end but when I refresh the page it does not retain its value.

I have hard coded the id in this example.

If I need to create an actionEditable method, has anyone done this and can post how?

Kind regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right so far. The method is pretty straightforward, as there is an existing component for that. Put the following code into your controller and call `image/editableSaver`

```
public function actionEditableSaver()
{
    Yii::import('path.to.editable.EditableSaver');
    $es = new EditableSaver('MyModel');
    $es->update();
}
```

Comment: Had to make a couple of changes because of the prefix in my widget names (see comment below). But your suggestion worked a charm!

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me.

in my admin.php view I had this code:

```
'editable' => array(
    'url' => $this->createUrl('image/editableSaver'),
    'placement' => 'right',
    'inputclass' => 'span3'
),
```

And in my corresponding controller I had this (as per @schmunk's) comment. With slight changes.

```
public function actionEditableSaver()
{
    Yii::import('bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableSaver');
    $es = new TbEditableSaver('Image');
    $es->update();
}
```

So I needed to change

```
public function actionEditableSaver()
{
    Yii::import('path.to.editable.EditableSaver');
    $es = new EditableSaver('MyModel');
    $es->update();
}
```

to

```
public function actionEditableSaver()
{
    Yii::import('bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableSaver');
    $es = new TbEditableSaver('Image');
    $es->update();
}
```

To correspond to the Tb prefix in my widget names (as downloaded from http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/getting-started.html)

I hope this helps someone else.